# Installing Event::Lib in CitrusPerl install on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: perl, cpan, perl-module, libevent

I'm working on a Perl project that requires Event::Lib.  I'm on MacOS 10.7, and am running [Citrus Perl](http://www.citrusperl.com/) instead of the system Perl.  I installed [libevent](http://libevent.org/) from source and it compiled fine.  But, when I go to install Event::Lib, I run into some errors:

```
cp Lib/Event/Lib.pm blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm
Skip blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm (unchanged)
/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/bin/perl /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Lib.xs > Lib.xsc && mv Lib.xsc Lib.c
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/include -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp -arch i386 -B/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/gcc -B/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/gcc -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -Duselargefiles -DPERL_RELOCATABLE_INCPUSH -fno-merge-constants -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector  -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.03\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.03\"  "-I/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/CORE"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  Lib.c
Lib.xs: In function ‘boot_Event__Lib’:
Lib.xs:275: error: ‘LOG_LEVEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Lib.xs:275: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Lib.xs:275: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [Lib.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what to try next?

EDIT:  After attempting some 'o conf' options:

```
cpan[1]> o conf makepl_arg "INC=-I/usr/local/include LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -levent"                                                             
    makepl_arg         [INC=-I/usr/local/include LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -levent]
Your /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/vendor/lib/CPAN/Config.pm file
is not writable. I will attempt to write your configuration to
/Users/username/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm instead.

Old configuration file /Users/username/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm
    moved to /Users/username/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm.bak
commit: wrote '/Users/username/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'

cpan[2]> install Event::Lib                                                                                                                     
Reading '/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 07 Feb 2013 21:53:02 GMT
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Reading '/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Reading '/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
  Database was generated on Thu, 14 Feb 2013 15:41:03 GMT
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Reading '/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/sources/modules/03modlist.data.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Writing /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/Metadata
Running install for module 'Event::Lib'
Running make for V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/id/V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/sources/authors/id/V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Building V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz

Checking existance of libevent...ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
yes
Checking capabilities...
  event_set_log_callback...no
  event_priority_init...no
Additional defines:  

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Event::Lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp Lib/Event/Lib.pm blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm
Skip blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm (unchanged)
/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/bin/perl /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Lib.xs > Lib.xsc && mv Lib.xsc Lib.c
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/include -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -no-cpp-precomp -arch i386 -B/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include/gcc -B/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/gcc -isystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -DUSE_SITECUSTOMIZE -Duselargefiles -DPERL_RELOCATABLE_INCPUSH -fno-merge-constants -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector  -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.03\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.03\"  "-I/Users/username/code/CitrusPerl/lib/CORE"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  Lib.c
Lib.xs: In function ‘boot_Event__Lib’:
Lib.xs:275: error: ‘LOG_LEVEL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
Lib.xs:275: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
Lib.xs:275: error: for each function it appears in.)
make: *** [Lib.o] Error 1
  VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz              : make NO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work in about 10 minutes time.

- Use [Perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/)
- Use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh)

Then:

- brew install libevent
- perlbrew install perl-5.16.0
- perlbrew switch perl-5.16.0
- perl -MCPAN -e 'install Event::Lib'

I think the above are the best utilities to provide a proper development environment that you can switch up; IE you can switch Perl versions of the fly.  Additionally they wont impact your native system.  Anyways if you decide not to use the aforementioned, your particular error looks to be about a missing header file.  I would assert that the libevent headers are indeed in /usr/local/include.

Good luck.

Comment: FYI - you might not need to use Perl Brew.  Try installing libevent via homebrew first.

Comment: I'd like to use CitrusPerl.  I'm running Padre, and CitrusPerl installs with the Wx library widgets.

I tried installing libevent from brew, and it installed fine.  Same error on Event::Lib install.

Comment: Maybe you will have better luck if you build libevent as a universal lib.

# brew uninstall libevent
# brew install libevent --universal

CPAN:
o conf makepl_arg "INC=-I/usr/local/include LIBS=-L/usr/local/lib -levent"
install Event::Lib

Comment: Tried it, same issue.  I'm not sure if the o conf options took.  Output added above.

Comment: I think the next thing to try would be to build the package yourself.  Download Event::Lib, extract it and use citrus perls binary to run against the MakeFile.PL.  It might elude to some errors that CPAN is suppressing.  Then run make.

Comment: Got it working.  You were right, it required universal, and I had the quotes in the wrong place on the INC line.  That's what I get for copy/pasting.  Should have been `INC=-I/usr/local/include LIBS="-L/usr/local/lib -levent"`.  I'm not 100% sure it works (I get a 'bus error: 10' when I try a `perl -e "use Event::Lib;"`, but I'm satisfied it's installed.  Thanks!