# Perl Event::Lib install fails all tests in OSX 10.8

Tags: perl, cpan, libevent

I'm running **Mac OSX 10.8.3**; I installed **libevent 2.0.21** (universal) with **homebrew**; I manage a private **Perl 5.16** environment with **perlbrew**.  I'm having trouble installing the CPAN module Event::Lib -- specifically, every single test fails.

When I force installation, **perl -e 'use Event::Lib;'** segfaults.

I suspect this has something to do with the libevent installation: in the attached log, there are warnings about directories not being found when checking for the existence of libevent, but nothing definitively stating that libevent couldn't be found.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779090/installing-eventlib-in-citrusperl-install-on-mac-os-x-10-7) describes a similar sounding problem, but the solution involved compiling libevent as a universal, which I've tried.

Any suggestions?  Install log follows.

```
~  cpanm --reinstall Event::Lib

--> Working on Event::Lib
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Event-Lib-1.03 ... OK
Building and testing Event-Lib-1.03 ... FAIL
! Installing Event::Lib failed. See /Users/chap/.cpanm/build.log for details.

~  cat .cpanm/build.log 

cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.5018 on perl 5.016001 built for darwin-2level
Work directory is /Users/chap/.cpanm/work/1370047478.40810
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.04
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Event::Lib on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Event::Lib
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/V/VP/VPARSEVAL/Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking Event-Lib-1.03.tar.gz
Entering Event-Lib-1.03
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Configuring Event-Lib-1.03
Running Makefile.PL
Checking existance of libevent...ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/sw/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
yes
Checking capabilities...
  event_set_log_callback...yes
  event_priority_init...yes
Additional defines:  -DHAVE_LOG_CALLBACKS -DHAVE_PRIORITIES 

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Event::Lib
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.63_02)
Building and testing Event-Lib-1.03
cp Lib/Event/Lib.pm blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm
Skip blib/lib/Event/Lib.pm (unchanged)
/Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/bin/perl /Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/lib/site_perl/5.16.1/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/lib/5.16.1/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap  Lib.xs > Lib.xsc && mv Lib.xsc Lib.c
cc -c   -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include  -O3   -DVERSION=\"1.03\" -DXS_VERSION=\"1.03\"  "-I/Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/lib/5.16.1/darwin-2level/CORE"  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_LOG_CALLBACKS -DHAVE_PRIORITIES  Lib.c
Running Mkbootstrap for Event::Lib ()
chmod 644 Lib.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/Event/Lib/Lib.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/lib" env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 cc  -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector Lib.o  -o blib/arch/auto/Event/Lib/Lib.bundle   \
       -levent -lm      \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/Event/Lib/Lib.bundle
cp Lib.bs blib/arch/auto/Event/Lib/Lib.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/Event/Lib/Lib.bs
Manifying blib/man3/Event::Lib::Event::Lib.3
Manifying blib/man3/Event::Lib.3
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /Users/chap/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.1/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_pod.t ....................... ok
t/00_pod_coverage.t .............. ok
t/01_event-lib.t ................. 
Failed 2/2 subtests 
t/10_event.t ..................... 

[*** snip ***]

t/62_events_readded.t ............ 
No subtests run 
t/63_events_readded.t ............ 
No subtests run 
t/64_pending_events_destroyed.t .. 
No subtests run 
t/65_stress_no_clone.t ........... 
No subtests run 
t/70_misc.t ...................... 
Failed 4/4 subtests 
t/71_misc.t ...................... 
Failed 2/2 subtests 
t/72_misc.t ...................... 
Failed 1/1 subtests 
t/73_misc.t ...................... 
Failed 26/26 subtests 
t/80_processes.t ................. 
No subtests run 
t/90_leak.t ...................... 
No subtests run 
t/91_leak.t ...................... 
No subtests run 
t/92_leak.t ...................... 
No subtests run 
t/93_leak.t ...................... 
No subtests run 

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/01_event-lib.t               (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.
t/10_event.t                   (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.

[*** snip ***]

t/93_leak.t                    (Wstat: 11 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero wait status: 11
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=36, Tests=2,  6 wallclock secs ( 0.10 usr  0.06 sys +  0.59 cusr  0.11 csys =  0.86 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 34/36 test programs. 0/2 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing Event::Lib failed. See /Users/chap/.cpanm/build.log for details.
~
```

Comment: Maybe libevent was built using a different compiler or different options???

Comment: Event::Lib hasn't seen an update since 2007.  If you don't specifically need libevent consider a different event handling module or threads?

Comment: I used perlbrew to install 5.14.4, and cpanm to reinstall Event::Lib into that environment.  Even though there were some test errors preventing Event::Lib from installing without --force, it no longer segfaults as before.  I am using this as a learning/prototyping tool for a libevent-driven app, so I strongly prefer something using libevent.  Further testing will confirm whether or not the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [the patch in this bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=80644)?

Comment: I may try this, but (see above) my problem is definitely related to Perl version 5.16, as is the bug report, and I can get by for my purposes on 5.14 for now.  +1 for the clue.

Comment: The patch fixed the problem in 5.16.